# Product genaration in featureIDE does not generate correct combination of features for each product

Tags: eclipse-plugin, software-product-lines

I am using featureIDE and want to automatically generate all valid Products from a feature model. I tried Product generation option of featureIDE with a simple model and some constraints. I expect to have nine valid Product in the end and the number is correct, but when I check the combination of the features in each configuration file, some features are missing in some of the Products.

Here is the model: [image: model]

I expect the following combination of features :

P1: t1 _4 v1

P2: t1 _4 v3

P3: t1 _5 v3

P4: t2 _5 v1

P5: t2 _10 v1

P6: t3 _5 v2

P7: t3 _5 v3

P8: t3 _10 v2

P9: t3 _10 v3

But I get only a few of them with the right combination of features, and most of them have missing features or double ones.

Below are shown some of the configurations that I get.

[image: here]

Anyone has run to this issue before?

Thank you!